# Should I set monitor on top of Mac mini?

Tags: mac, display

I've just bought a Mac mini and would like to have it sitting directly under my monitor which is a Dell G2410 24" Widescreen LED Monitor.

Is it safe to set the monitor directly on top of the Mac mini in terms of damaged the Mac mini chassis? I'm not concerned with interference to wifi as I have the mac mini hard wired to the network.

Ideally I would like to buy something like [this](http://www.macessitywebstore.com/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=STANDBYMI-V2), but it is too expensive to get shipped to the UK.

But I would be more than happy setting my monitor directly on top of the Mac mini - perhaps with a bit of foam padding in between to stop it from getting scratched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the newest Mac Minis have a built in power supply and so use the aluminium chassis to dissipate heat. Placing your monitor on the top of the Mac Mini could reduce that dissipation and have a detrimental effect on it's lifespan.

Cheers,

Maurice

Comment: Yeah I've thought about that, but according to the following thread, heat dissipation will only be a concern if the object on top actually generates heat (such as a second Mac mini for example).
http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1153142

Comment: That's quite an old thread - from the days when the Mac Mini has no built in power supply. My understanding is that Apple used aluminium enclosures to assist in heat dissipation (and they look good too :-) ) If you put anything thermally non-conductive (e.g. a monitor stand) onto that top surface it will act as an insulator and *may* compromise the effectiveness of heat dissipation. I advise that you check the paperwork that comes with the Mini - I would be surprised if Apple didn't warn you about putting things on top of the Mini.

Answer (score 0):

If the stand doesn't go the full width of the mini, I'd place something simple like a plank of wood between, anything you want that doesn't look out of place while spreading the weight.

Comment: The stand is slightly wider than the Mac mini, and I'll be padding with foam, so the weight should be spread pretty evenly, right?